# Query to get records from table on basis of one field and to check that if the field is not -1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named **Documents**, with the fields **Document_ID**(primary key) and **Cluster_ID** , now i want all the Document_ID that have same Cluster_ID, on basis on Document_ID (passed as parameter), default value of Cluster_ID is  '-1'.

eg: **dbo.Documents**

```
 Document ID ********   Cluster_ID

 - 1******************          -1
 - 2******************             1001
 - 3******************             1001
 - 4******************             -1
 - 5******************             1002
 - 6******************             1001
 - 7******************              -1
 - 8******************              -1
 - 9******************              -1
```

now, 
if Document_ID is 2 then i want result as rows with Document_ID=2,3,6  , here i am not able to handle records with cluster_ID=-1;(because -1 id default value to the table and there are hundreds of matching records in table)

i tried a query mentioned below which is working fine but when i execute the query for Document_ID=7 it will return 5 rows with cluster_ID=-1,

```
SELECT d2.* 
FROM dbo.Documents d1 
join dbo.Documents d2 on d1.Cluster_ID=d2.Cluster_ID 
WHERE d1.Document_ID =2
```

**my issue is:**
It is returning all the rows from table which has Cluster_ID=-1, what i want is, If Cluster_ID=-1,return single row else return all rows with the same cluster_ID

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected results? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: just show your select query am i mean what you have tried so far

Comment: i want results, as 3 rows with Document_ID=2,3 and 6

Comment: @asmita - please show us the output table or result set you expect. You have to be clear about what you want.

Comment: @asmita Could you print the value of `@DocumentId` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT
    Document_ID,
    Cluster_ID
FROM Documents
WHERE Cluster_ID =
(
    SELECT
        Cluster_ID
    FROM Documents
    WHERE Document_ID = @Document_ID
)
AND Cluster_ID <> -1

UNION

SELECT
    Document_ID,
    Cluster_ID
FROM Documents
WHERE Document_ID = @Document_ID 
AND Cluster_ID = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
here **@doumentId** is parameter which you need to pass.

```
DECLARE @Cluster_ID int
 SET Cluster_ID = (
    SELECT Cluster_ID
    FROM
    FROM Documents
    WHERE Document_ID = @documentId
    )

IF Cluster_ID > 0
BEGIN
 SELECT *
 FROM Documents
 WHERE Cluster_ID = (
        SELECT Cluster_ID
        FROM Documents
        WHERE Document_ID = @documentId
        )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM
    FROM Documents
    WHERE Document_ID = @documentId
END
```

Comment: It is returning all the rows from table which has Cluster_ID=-1, what i want is, If Cluster_ID=-1,return single row else return all rows with the same cluster_ID

Comment: if you are putting where condition 'WHERE Document_ID = @documentId' then how can it return row with cluster_ID=-1

Comment: because @Document_ID, i am passing has cluster_ID=-1

Answer (score 0):

You need two queries that you combine with UNION ALL. The first gives you all desired records in case Cluster_ID doesn't equal -1. The second gives you the one record for the case that Cluster_ID equals -1. So you get either records from the first part or the record from the second part.

```
select Document_ID, Cluster_ID
from dbo.Documents
where Cluster_ID in
(
  select nullif(Cluster_ID, -1)
  from dbo.Documents
  where Document_ID = @Document_ID 
)
UNION ALL
select Document_ID, Cluster_ID
from dbo.Documents
where Document_ID = @Document_ID and Cluster_ID = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this IF\Else query

```
DECLARE @Cluster_ID int;
SELECT @Cluster_ID=Cluster_ID FROM Documents WHERE Document_ID=@Document_ID;
IF @Cluster_ID=-1
BEGIN
SELECT Document_ID,Cluster_ID FROM Documents WHERE Document_ID=@Document_ID;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT Document_ID,Cluster_ID FROM Documents WHERE Cluster_ID=@Cluster_ID;
END
```

This query will take the clusterid and then based on whether it's -1 or not returns single row or all rows

Comment: hi, i wanted a solution which takes Document_Id and returns result,

Comment: You will have to pass only document_id to this query...the cluster_id will be taken by the query itself